# What should be the query?

Tags: sql, database, relational-database

We have following 4 database tables

**School**

```
 School_ID,  School_Name
```

**Student**

```
Student_id, School_ID, Student Name
```

**Course**

```
Course_ID, Course_Name
```

**Course_Student**

```
Course_Id, Student ID
```

Please suggest a query which returns the list of schools whose each student is enrolled in  at least 3 subjects.

Comment: Please **first show us your efforts!** [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Oh no no ... it is just a part of very huge query(I am working on other parts:views, triggers and storedProcedure).It is an urgent thing that's y i thought to ask for some help from my stackoverflow's fellows :) ....I changed the name of entities and their keys to make it easily understandable(i think because of entity names u ppl think that it is a homework)

Comment: All the following queries are wrong ... I have designed the query which runs perfectly and gives correct answer... Thanks everyone for help.

Answer (score 2):

Given Schema

```
CREATE TABLE School
    (`School_ID` int, `School_Name` varchar(7))
;

INSERT INTO School
    (`School_ID`, `School_Name` )
VALUES
    (1, 'SchoolA'),
    (2, 'SchoolB'),
    (3, 'SchoolC')
;

CREATE TABLE Student
    (`Student_id` int, `School_ID` int, `Student_Name` varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO Student
    (`Student_id`, `School_ID`, `Student_Name`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'John'),
    (2, 1, 'Alex'),
    (3, 2, 'Lex')
;

CREATE TABLE Course
    (`Course_ID` int, `Course_Name` varchar(9))
;

INSERT INTO Course
    (`Course_ID`, `Course_Name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Math'),
    (2, 'Science'),
    (3, 'Chemistry'),
    (4, 'Physics'),
    (5, 'History')
;



CREATE TABLE Course_Student
    (`Course_ID` int, `Student_ID` int)
;

INSERT INTO Course_Student
    (`Course_ID`, `Student_ID`)
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (2, 1),
    (3, 1),
    (1, 2),
    (1, 3),
    (2, 3),
    (4, 2),
    (5, 2)
;
```

The expected output of the schema above will be `SchoolA` because it is the only School that has all students who are enrolled on atleast three courses.

```
SELECT SCHOOL_ID, School_Name
FROM
(
    SELECT  d.SCHOOL_ID, e.School_Name,e.NoOfStudents
    FROM
        (
          SELECT  a.Student_ID, a.school_ID
          FROM    Student a
                  INNER JOIN Course_Student c
                      ON c.Student_ID = a.Student_ID
                  INNER JOIN Course d
                      ON c.Course_ID = d.Course_ID
          GROUP BY a.Student_ID, a.school_ID
          HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
        ) d INNER JOIN
        (
          SELECT  b.School_ID, b.School_Name, COUNT(*) NoOfStudents
          FROM    Student a
                  INNER JOIN School b
                      ON a.School_ID = b.School_ID
          GROUP BY b.School_ID, b.School_Name
        ) e ON e.School_ID = d.School_ID
    GROUP BY d.SCHOOL_ID
    HAVING COUNT(*) = e.NoOfStudents
) s
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6dacc/1)

Comment: This will only return schools that have **at least one student** enrolled in 3 or more courses. It needs an extra count per school to be equal to the total number of students in that school.

Answer (score 1):

```
select School_name from School
where School_ID not in (
    select School_ID from Student 
    inner join Course_Student on Student.Student_id = Course_Student.[Student ID]
    group by Student_ID, School_ID, Course_Id
    having Count(Course_Id) < 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select School_Name, Student_Name, count(Course_Student.Course_ID) as total from School
inner join Student
on Course_Student.School_ID = Student.School_ID
inner join Course
on Student.Student_Id = Course.Student_Id
where total > 3
group by School_Name, Student_Name
```

Comment: Please suggest a query which returns **the list of schools**

Comment: This could return schools where some of the students are enrolled in fewer than three courses.

Comment: Actually, I think it will return an error: #1054 - Unknown column 'total' in 'where clause'